# HTML / CSS navigation bar

Tags: html, nav

I am trying to move the register button on my nav bar to the left, while having the rest on the left, could somebody help?

my code;

```
     <html>
   <head>
    <style>

    ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:#005EB8;
}

li {
 float: right;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #003087;
}
</style>
<body>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="doctors.html">DOCTOR LOGIN</a></li>    
    <li><a href="login.html">MHS LOGIN</a></li>
    <li><a href="admin.html">ADMIN LOGIN</a></li>
    <li><a href="ourdoctors.html">OUR DOCTORS</a></li>
    <li><a href="story.html">OUR STORY</a></li>
    <li><a href="findus.html">FIND US</a></li>
    <li><a href="register.html">REGISTER</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

sorry if my code is really bad

Comment: Do you mean you want to move it to the right?

Comment: i would like to keep doctors, login admin our doctors, story findus on the right hand side, but have register isolated on the left hand side of the nav bar (if possible?)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `float` attribute:

```
   <body>
    <ul>
    <li style="float:left"><a href="register.html">REGISTER</a></li>
    <li><a href="doctors.html">DOCTOR LOGIN</a></li>    
    <li><a href="login.html">MHS LOGIN</a></li>
    <li><a href="admin.html">ADMIN LOGIN</a></li>
    <li><a href="ourdoctors.html">OUR DOCTORS</a></li>
    <li><a href="story.html">OUR STORY</a></li>
    <li><a href="findus.html">FIND US</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: i want to isolate register to the left hand side of the nav bar, whilst having the rest on the right hand side

Answer (score 1):

Add the following:

```css
 ul li:last-child {
            float: left;
  }
```